# Rails xapi call to scorm cloud fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to send data from Rails to an LRS. At the moment, testing is happening using SCORM cloud. I have a valid endpoint and authentication values. The data is being sent from the controller, but the server is refusing it. I have tested the xapi statement in http://tincanapi.com/statement-generator - it validates and sends. I have added statements/ to the end of the endpoint which has stopped it moaning about malformed URL.

Full error result

```
Started GET "/sendx" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-01 18:20:28 +0000
Started GET "/sendx" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-01 18:20:28 +0000
Processing by SendxapisController#send as HTML
Processing by SendxapisController#send as HTML
  Lrsconfig Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "lrsconfigs".* FROM "lrsconfigs" WHERE "lrscon
figs"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Lrsconfig Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "lrsconfigs".* FROM "lrsconfigs" WHERE "lrscon
figs"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
opening connection to cloud.scorm.com:443...
opened
starting SSL for cloud.scorm.com:443...
SSL established
<- "POST /tc/E9D3QJZJST/sandbox/statements/?actor[mbox]=mailto%3AKarl%40example.
com&actor[name]=Karl&verb[id]=http%3A%2F%2Fadlnet.gov%2Fexpapi%2Fverbs%2Fanswere
d&verb[display][en-US]=answered&object[id]=http%3A%2F%2Fadlnet.gov%2Fexpapi%2Fac
tivities%2Fexample&object[definition][name][en-US]=Karl%20Activity&object[defini
tion][description][en-US]=Karl%20activity%20description HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type
: application/json\r\nX-Experience-Api-Version: 1.0.0\r\nAuthorization: Basic Zl
dIQjFWSGtid3lVLWFCUTNkVTpzSVpKQnRwT1hWS2lPc2QzbTZB\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost:
 cloud.scorm.com\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n"
<- ""
-> "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n"
-> "Content-Length: 37\r\n"
-> "Connection: close\r\n"
-> "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Content-Length,Authorization,If-M
atch,If-None-Match,X-Experience-API-Version,X-Experience-API-Consistent-Through\
r\n"
-> "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE\r\n"
-> "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n"
-> "Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag,Last-Modified,Cache-Control,Content-Type
,Content-Length,WWW-Authenticate,X-Experience-API-Version,X-Experience-API-Consi
stent-Through\r\n"
-> "Date: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 18:20:28 GMT\r\n"
-> "Server: Apache\r\n"
-> "X-Experience-API-Version: 1.0.0\r\n"
-> "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block\r\n"
-> "X-Cache: Error from cloudfront\r\n"
-> "Via: 1.1 f5d27f80802e2b6e66ec3970da5568b8.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)\r\n"
-> "X-Amz-Cf-Id: I4IiYfXehWEqBN04LhHpCdhivUq8_6xrBCztJQemPHg8cV7vjhElEg==\r\n"
-> "\r\n"
reading 37 bytes...
-> "Missing required argument: statements"
read 37 bytes
Conn close
```

Code that generates this

```
@lrsconfig = Lrsconfig.find(1)
@auth = { username: @lrsconfig.lrsusername, password: @lrsconfig.lrspassword }
@header = {
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'X-Experience-API-Version' => @lrsconfig.XAPIversion
}

@xapi = {
    "actor": 
    {
        "mbox": "mailto:Karl@example.com",
        "name": "Karl"
    },
    "verb": {
        "id": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/answered",
        "display": {
            "en-US": "answered"
        }
    },
    "object": {
        "id": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/example",
        "definition": {
            "name": {
                "en-US": "Karl Activity"
            },
            "description": {
                "en-US": "Karl activity description"
            }
        }
    }
}


# Make and send an xAPI call
response = HTTParty.post(@lrsconfig.lrsendpoint,
    basic_auth: @auth,
    headers: @header,
    query: @xapi,
    #body: @xapi,
    debug_output: $stdout
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks from the error message as though SCORM cloud can't read the statement from the HTTP request.  There could be a couple of reasons for this.

Firstly, you have the @xapi object being sent in the query rather than the body (it looks like you've tried a few things here, but body is where it should live).  Secondly, your @xapi object is a Ruby object when you send it, rather than a JSON object.  You need to assign @xapi.to_json to the body, rather than just @xapi.